# Order of Operation Mathematical

Tags: python-3.x, math

new to programming and came across this while doing a worksheet:

```
x = 1 / 2 + 3 // 3 + 4 ** 2
```

what is `x`?

I read that in regards to the exponent you have to read it right to left, and I did that and I keep getting 0 for some reason even though the answer was supposed to be 17.5. Any help on why/how I am supposed to get 17.5 and the order I was supposed to work it out from would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine the order of precedence for this expression, keep in mind these rules (non-exhaustive):

- evaluation goes from left to right
- Multiplication/division has higher precedence than addition/subtraction (e.g. `1 + 2 / 3` gets evaluated as `1 + (2 / 3)`)
- Exponent/power has higher precedence than multiplication and division (e.g. `1 / 2**4` gets evaluated as `1 / (2**4)`)

These rules together show us that this expression:

```
x = 1 / 2 + 3 // 3 + 4 ** 2
```

Will be evaluated as:

```
x = (1 / 2) + (3 // 3) + (4 ** 2)
```

Therefore, x = 0.5 + 1 + 16 = 17.5.

Comment: Thanks a lot been a while since I did maths and i thought I had to use the addition operators as I saw it. So the exponent then the addition then the floor division then the addition again. Thanks so much for the clarification.

Comment: @Josh Glad this helps! If this answered your question, please consider upvoting this post or  accepting it as answer. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Using Python, the result is 17.5

[image]

You can check the order of the mathematical operators in python (Python Operator Precedence) for more information

```
(1 / 2) + (3 // 3) + (4 ** 2) = 0.5 + 1 + 16
```

Ref:
https://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html

Answer (score 0):

The operator precedence is defined in the Python documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

So, `**` has the highest precedence, then `/` and `//` and then `+`.